# Css set left fixed and right fluid layout

Tags: html, css, sass

I need to do with html and css such layout:
left width is static for 250px
right is fluid, for other rest of screen (100%-250px)

I try so(i'm using sass):

```
  .wrapper{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .left{
      width:250px;
      float:left;
    }
    .right{
      float:right;
      width:100%;
      margin-left: 250px;
    }
  }
```

So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: You could make `.left, .right { display: table-cell }` instead of floating them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/ExHzk/
If you can't see the fiddle, here's the html and css.

HTML:

```
<div class="fixed"></div>
<div class="fluid"></div>​
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
}

.fluid {
    margin-left: 250px;
}
```

**Aside**
I left out the wrapper. It's not really relevant for the demonstration. One question though: If you're giving the wrapper a width of 100%, what's the margin: 0 auto for? And do you really need to specify the width?

Comment: width:auto instead of margin-left then you can change your margin in one place.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code if I have understand well:

```
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .left{
      width:250px;
      float:left;
    }
    .right{
      float:right;
      width:100%;
      margin-right: 250px;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could just remove the `float:right` on the .right like:

```
right{
  width:100%;
  margin-left: 250px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RfHqX/

Notice that I didn't use SASS-style.

Answer (score -1):

use `margin` not `float` for `right div`

```
.wrapper{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    .left{
      width:250px;
  height:100%;
      float:left;
    background:#f00;
    }
    .right{

      height:100%;
      margin-left: 250px;
    background:#0f0;
    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/exeloz/3/edit)**