# Navbar on left of page, how to let content resize to match screen size?

Tags: html, css

So - I've got a website, and for navigation, I have a bar on the left in a div:

```
#menu {
float : left; 
border-style : dashed none; 
border-width : 1px; 
font-family : Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
width : 190px; 
margin-top : 20px; 
}
```

And content on the right, also in a div:

```
#content {
padding-top : 10px; 
margin-top : 20px; 
position : relative; 
width : 760px; 
float : right; 
}
```

And it's all contained in a div called page:

```
#page {
width : 100%; 
margin-left : 30px; 
margin-right : auto; ; 
}
```

And it looks fine when the screen size matches the 960px width of the page, but if it doesn't, the content doesn't expand or shrink to fit. But if I put width:100% in the #content CSS, then the content pane appears at the bottom, since it can't fit to the right of it.

How can I fix it so the menu div will have that 190px width, and the content div will take whatever's left?

I am not using any other frameworks, so solutions which require jquery are of no use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13032122/css-set-left-fixed-and-right-fluid-layout

Comment: http://www.pagecolumn.com/liquidfixed/2_col_fix_liquid.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calc()`([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)) in CSS for modern browsers:

```
#content {
 padding-top : 10px; 
 margin-top : 20px; 
 position : relative; 
 width : calc(100% - 190px); 
 float : right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a crude demo of a method I used recently:

http://codepen.io/samanthamiller/pen/gwFse

The trick is to set the #content width to 100%, then put a margin-left of the width of your sidebar, then position the sidebar absolutely to the side. Doesn't work for all cases but worked well for me.

HTML:

```
<div id="page">
  <div id="content">
    Content here 
  </div>  
  <div id="menu">
    Menu here
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Reset */
* {margin:0;box-sizing:border-box;}

/* Full height */
html,body,#page,#content {min-height:100%;height:100%;}

/* Fixed-width left column */
#page {background:red;position:relative;}
#content {background:green;margin-left:190px;padding:10px;}
#menu {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:190px;padding:10px;}
```